# Jquery check if data exist as a substring on an html table

Tags: javascript, validation, url

Check if data exist on an html table even if it is a substring.

```
var substring = 'find me'; //substring or data that you wanted to check

var dataExist = [];

$('table#tableID tr').each(function () {
    var arrayOfThisRow = [];
    var tableData = $(this).find('td');
    if (tableData.length > 0) {
        if($(this).text().indexOf(substring) == -1)
            dataExist.push(true);
    }
});

console.log(dataExist.includes(true))
```

Comment: What is the specific problem or question?

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to figure out if a table has a string anywhere in it, you could simply use **indexOf()** on **myTable.innerText**.

```
var myTable = document.getElementById('myTable');
var exists = myTable.innerHTML.indexOf('find me');
```

If you want to make sure the **exists** variable is always a boolean, you can use the below line.

```
var exists = !! ~ document.getElementById('tableID').innerHTML.indexOf('find me');
```